# PHP Date Timestamp wrong

Tags: php

I can't for the life of me figure why the unix timestamp returned from the code below shows up as Fri, 31 Aug 2012 06:26:00 GMT. I have tested this on my server as well as http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm. The date/time returned should actually be Fri, 31 Aug 2012 02:26:41 PM.

```
$stringtime = strtotime(DATE("m/d/y G:i", STRTOTIME("2012-08-31 02:26:41")));
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

Comment: Guess the 41 seconds is just a miss spell?

Answer (score 4):

Unix timestamps are always GMT (no time offset). You might need to set your offset either in your php.ini or in your code to allow for the 4 hour difference you are seeing.

Comment: Yeah, the time difference seems about right for an EDT (GMT -4) time. Change the settings in your php.ini file on your server, or set the timezone using `date_default_timezone_set`. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for documentation on that function.

Comment: @Chaser324 Thanks for adding the link in the comment, au.php.net seems to flaky as heck at the moment, was waiting for it to pop open to add the link to my answer. +1

Comment: No problem. The php.net site seems a bit flaky at the moment for me here in the US too.

Comment: It's not a timezone issue. The input time doesn't specify a time zone so it wouldn't convert it (it's assumed to be local). Look at his format string. It doesn't match the output. Its only using G for GMT formatted output

Comment: Try us.PHP.net when the main site is down

Comment: @RobertMaysJr *His input string doesn't specify what time zone* - which is the exact problem. Unix Timestamps are *always* GMT - so unless he is living in Olso, the time being returned is wrong by his offset.

Comment: It is not correct to say UNIX timestamps are in GMT. They have no timezone at all. They are the number of seconds since a fixed point in time, which happens to be 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Comment: @fluffeh But it would assume his input time was GMT. So no timezone conversion would occur. So if you are right where did the 4 hours come from.  Trust me I'm sure. Timezones suck I deal with them all the time at work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the timezone first using `date_default_timezone_set` function, i.e.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

[**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` converts the input string to a unix timestamp. If your input string has no timezone information, PHP must guess at which timezone you mean. It doesn't really guess... it looks at your default time zone.

The UNIX timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 UTC. So if you do this:

```
echo strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
// depends on your default time zone
```

you might expect zero. But you aren't specifying a timezone in the string, so it will use the default timezone. The actual output will vary.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
// always 0
```

Now it will be zero. Or you can remove the ambiguity:

```
echo strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC');
// always 0
```

Likewise, when you use `date()`, PHP applies the default timezone when displaying the time.

The code in your question does not actually show where your error is. So I cannot really tell you what your problem is, other than you don't understand how PHP works with time stamps and time zones.

If your time stamp is correct, then you probably just need to use `date_default_timezone_set()` to set your timezone. That will affect all future calls to `date()`.

You also may be interested in using the `DateTime` class, which is more straightforward than counting seconds from 1970.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use G.  That converts it to Gmt and its the only format character its using. You just have the format string wrong

'D, d M Y h:i:s A'

$stringtime = date( 'D, d M Y h:i:s A' , strtotime("2012-08-31 02:26:41"));

Comment: G inside the string is nothing to do with GMT. `G 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros - 0 through 23`